# Achieving video call capabilities inside a HoloLens app, simultaneously see the video call window and see the Holograms

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality, remote-assistance

A client has requested to make an app where they are able to see the holograms as well as a video call window inside the application for assistance remotely. We were previously using Microsoft dynamic 365 remote assistance to achieve assistance inside an app. But the Microsoft dynamic 365 remote assistance doesn't show the video inside another app and only audio is working.

So my question, Is it possible to see the hologram in an app as well as a the video from Microsoft dynamic 365 remote assistance

If not, how can this use case be achieved.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Commenting this thread to follow